# As a software developer, is there a way I can restrict Google Home to only play certain music?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I have a Google Home.  As a joke, I would like to program mine to answer any requests to play music with something like "Sorry, I can only play music by Taylor Swift" or some artist or playlist of my choice.  I have Spotify premium as my music service.

I looked briefly at the Google Home API, and it looks like you can program new actions.  Is there some way I can intercept requests for music and filter them with this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, any Action that is intended to imitate Google Home system functionality is explicitly banned, and the API doesn't really facilitate doing that (not surprising, I suppose, that the API doesn't let you do something that Google doesn't want you to do!):

> We don't allow actions that **mimic or interfere with device or Assistant functionality**. Examples of prohibited behaviour include:
>
> - Using a voice for your action that mimics the Google Assistant's voice.
> - Mimicking system notifications or warnings.
> - **Pretending to be Google or another Google action.**

([Actions on Google: Policies for Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#naming))

[There is a fixed invocation pattern](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/#action_invocation) that Actions use to be invoked, generally. The image in their documentation explains most clearly:

[image: Invocation Discovery Grammar]

<sup>Image from [Actions on Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/#action_invocation); [CC BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/).</sup>

You can also use [action phrases](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/#providing_good_action_phrases), such as ""hear a fun fact"
or "give me a 5 minute workout", but undoubtedly the Google Action takes precedence to yours.

As an aside, it appears [you can override Alexa Skills](https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/67jrzw/override_alexas_built_in_commands_with_your/) in the way you're hoping.